# Microsoft Graph API return ErrorInvalidMailboxItemId error "Item Id doesn't belong to the current mailbox"

Tags: api, graph, archive

Microsoft Graph API returns ErrorInvalidMailboxItemId error "Item Id doesn't belong to the current mailbox" while getting mailfolder from In place archive.

The endpoint was working previously but not now.

Microsoft has specified that Cross-mailbox API calls will fail starting April 15, 2020.

https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/blogs/accessing-outlook-items-in-a-users-archived-shared-or-delegated-mailboxes-using-microsoft-graph/

Is there any solution to access the In Place Archive  ?